# Learning Java classes and methods, getting this error while testing my code

Tags: java

I am following along with JAVA book for CS101 and trying to wrap my head around this exercise, but when I run my code, I keep getting this error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Riddle

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Riddle

JAVA CODE

```
public class Riddle{
        private String question;        //instance variables
        private String answer;
    
        public Riddle( String q, String a)      //constructor
        {
            question = q;
            answer = a;
        }
    
        public String getQuestion()     //instance method
        {
            return question;
        }
    
        public String getAnswer()
        {
            return answer;
        }
}
    
public class RiddleUser{
        public static void main ( String argv [] ){
            Riddle riddle1= new Riddle (
                "What is black and white and red all over?",
                "An embarrassed zebra.");
            Riddle riddle2= new Riddle (
                "What is black and white and read all over?",
                "A newspaper." );
    
            System.out.println("Here are two riddles:");
            System.out.println(riddle1.getQuestion());
            System.out.println(riddle2.getQuestion());
            System.out.println("The answer to the first riddle is:");
            System.out.println(riddle1.getAnswer());
            System.out.println("The answer to the second riddle is:");
            System.out.println(riddle2.getAnswer());
       }
}
```

Here is the exercise I am doing, I also uploaded the PDF of the book, the exercise is on pages 71-73.
Basically, it wants to show you how to write a class and test it, If I am getting this correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH50B.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZYX6.jpg)

[enter link description here](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/%7Eram/jjj/jjj-os-20170625.pdf)

Comment: You have two classes here, `Riddle` and `RiddleUser`.  The code itself won't compile, so please tell us what's really going on.  It's possible these classes are in two separate projects in your IDE, or they're in two separate packages and you forgot the `import` statement.  Please add details to your question to explain where  these classes actually are.

Comment: It seems like `Riddle` class does not have main method.

Comment: Is all code in one Java file? Only one `public class` is allowed in Java.

Comment: @nkgcp "ClassNotFoundException" probably is not caused by a missing main method.  I think there's a different issue here.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the **entire** stack trace - as text and not as a screen capture.

Answer (score 4):

On a Java file, only 1 class can be public, the public class is the one with the main method.

The file and the public class must have the same name, RiddleUser.java in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring `RiddleUser` class in its own file.

> This should work if you add `private` scope modifier to the `RiddleUser` class, without declaring it in its own file aswell.

Say your source path folder is `~/riddle-project/src/`

```
riddle-project
└── src
    ├── Riddle.java
    └── RiddleUser.java
```

Execute the following:

```sh
# compile main class
$ javac src/Riddle.java

# run main class with specified class path 
$ java -classpath ./src/ Riddle
```

> **Class Path** is the directory that contains the `.class` compiled java files